# NoSuchElementException In Java inside lambda function(nested foreach loop)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, query-optimization, java-11

Is there any way we can improve the code mentioned below.

```
public SomeEntity saveGeneratedPriceInstructions(List<SomeDTOList> someDTOList, boolean force) {
         List<String> weekNames = PeriodsUtils.getWeekNames(someDTOList.get(0).getWeekName());
        String codeToReturn = someDTOList.get(0).getCode();
        Set<String> encounteredCode = new HashSet<>();
        List<Integer> oldPIList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<SomeEntity> uploadLogToSaveList = new ArrayList<>();
        modelPiWeekDTOList.stream().map(SomeDTO::getCode).forEach(code -> {
                    if (encounteredCode.contains(code))
                        return;
                    else {
                        encounteredCode.add(code);
                    }
                    SomeEntity oldPI = someRepository.findOneByCsuCodeEqualsAndWeekNumberEqualsAndApprovalStatusNotLikeOrderByUploadLogIdDesc(
                            Code, weekNames.get(0), APPROVED_STATUS);

//                remove if it is not necessary to support the week numbers without padding like w1_2020
                    if (oldPI == null && weekNames.size() == 2) {
                        oldPI = someRepository.findOneByCsuCodeEqualsAndWeekNumberEqualsAndApprovalStatusNotLikeOrderByUploadLogIdDesc(
                                Code, weekNames.get(1), APPROVED_STATUS);
                    }

                    if (oldPI != null) {
                        oldPIList.add(oldPI.getUploadLogId());
                    }
                    SomeEntity uploadLogToSave = new SomeEntity (Code, weekNames.get(0));
                    uploadLogToSaveList.add(uploadLogToSave);
                }
        );
        someRepository.deleteAllByIdInBatch(oldPIList);

//
        List<SomeEntity> someEntityList = (List<SomeEntity>) someRepository.saveAllAndFlush(uploadLogToSaveList);
        System.out.println("size" + someEntityList.size());

        Iterator<SomeEntity> uploadLogIdIterator = someEntityList.iterator();
        someDTOList.stream().map(SOmeDTO::getCode).forEach(code -> {
            int uploadId = uploadLogIdIterator.next().getUploadLogId();
            someDTOList.stream().filter(someDTO -> someDTO.getCode().equals(code)).forEach(product -> {
//                    // activate all the inactive products
                if (!product.isActive()) {
                    pricingProductService.activateProduct(Long.valueOf(product.getProductCode()));
                }
                product.setId(0);
                product.setUploadLogId(uploadId);
                Integer weekId = modelPiWeekService.saveModelPiWeekDtoRestful(product).getId();
                getModelPiWeekDeltaDTOStream(product).forEach(period -> modelPiWeekDeltaService.saveModelPiWeekDeltaDtoRestful(weekId, period));
            });
        });
        return someRepository.findOneByCsuCodeEqualsAndWeekNumberEqualsAndApprovalStatusEqualsOrderByUploadLogIdDesc(
                codeToReturn, weekNames.get(0), "C");
}
```

For some reason I am geeting this exception at this line
int uploadId = uploadLogIdIterator.next().getUploadLogId();

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:1000) ~[na:na]
    at com.arcelormittal.ninasteel.nina_ui.service.ModelPiWeekUploadLogService.lambda$saveGeneratedPriceInstructions$5(ModelPiWeekUploadLogService.java:150) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at com.arcelormittal.ninasteel.nina_ui.service.ModelPiWeekUploadLogService.saveGeneratedPriceInstructions(ModelPiWeekUploadLogService.java:149) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.arcelormittal.ninasteel.nina_ui.service.ModelPiWeekUploadLogService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$59a8179d.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

Can anyone provide me solution for this. I do not understand why it's giving me this error.

I am trying to add uploadlogId for particular product but at then end its moving to next element which is not present and throws this exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:1000) ~[na:na]
    at com.arcelormittal.ninasteel.nina_ui.service.ModelPiWeekUploadLogService.lambda$saveGeneratedPriceInstructions$5(ModelPiWeekUploadLogService.java:150) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at com.arcelormittal.ninasteel.nina_ui.service.ModelPiWeekUploadLogService.saveGeneratedPriceInstructions(ModelPiWeekUploadLogService.java:149) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.arcelormittal.ninasteel.nina_ui.service.ModelPiWeekUploadLogService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$59a8179d.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I fix this error?
Rather how can i fix/re-write this particular block to fix the above exception.

Comment: Not every code gets better with streams, especially the way you are using them. You are using `someDTOList.stream().map(SOmeDTO::getCode).forEach(code -> { … })`, to perform another `someDTOList.stream().filter(someDTO -> someDTO.getCode().equals(code)). …` inside the action, searching the entire list for the object you already had before the `.map(SOmeDTO::getCode)` step. A plain loop over `someDTOList` would be straight-forward, more readable and more efficient as after calling `getCode` on the DTO you could still access the DTO and wouldn’t think of searching the entire list for the object.

Answer (score 0):

`uploadLogIdIterator` is probably shorter (fewer elements) than the one you looping through in your `forEach` (or even empty) resulting in the iterator not finding the next element.

In any cases, this error is thrown when you are calling `next()` and there are no more elements.

I can't really give you a code fix because I must say I don't follow what you are trying to do with those streams and iterator...